# How to get max element at each index while comparing two arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, comparison, max

I have two indexed arrays of identical length:

```
$first_array = [1,3,4,5,6]; 
$second_array = [5,2,1,7,9];
```

I need to generate a new array that consists of the higher value between the two elements at each index.

The output should be:

```
$output_array[5, 3, 4, 7, 9];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Super easy one-liner:

Pass both arrays to `array_map()`, as it synchronously loops through both sets of data, call `max()` on the two elements.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8Eg00))

```
$first_array = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6];
$second_array = [5, 2, 1, 7, 9];

var_export(array_map('max', $first_array, $second_array));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 5,
  1 => 3,
  2 => 4,
  3 => 7,
  4 => 9,
)
```

Comment: Thanks, it's the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way. [demo](https://3v4l.org/cVR9F)

```
<?php

$first_array = array(1,3,4,5,6);
$second_array = array(5,2,1,7,9);

$return = array();
foreach($first_array as $key => $value){
    if($first_array[$key] > $second_array[$key]){
        $return[] = $first_array[$key];
    }else{
        $return[] = $second_array[$key];
    }
}

print_r($return);
```